# как вывести данные из json в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul class="menu" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<li class="item nav first"><a href="">{{ fio.alias }}</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункт1</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункт2</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункт3</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункты4</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункты5</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">Пункты6</a></li>
```

вот файл data.json

```html
{
  "avatarURL": "/avatar/628bffae-69d7-4b7a-ad83-b5eb8fbee492",
  "alias": "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
  "birthDate": 326419200,
  "pages": [
    {
      "network": "odnoklassniki",
      "id": "555555555555",
      "alias": "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
      "lastActivityTime": 1442880000,
      "cities": ["Россия, Москва"],
      "jobs": [],
      "phones": [],
      "emails": [],
      "devices": [],
      "salary": null,
      "marriageStatus": null
    },
    {
      "network": "vkontakte",
      "id": "55555555",
      "alias": "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
      "lastActivityTime": 1442880000,
      "cities": ["Россия, Москва"],
      "jobs": [],
      "phones": [],
      "emails": [],
      "devices": ["iPhone"],
      "salary": null,
      "marriageStatus": "married"
    },
    {
      "network": "odnoklassniki",
      "id": "100005555555555",
      "alias": "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
      "lastActivityTime": 1442880000,
      "cities": [],
      "jobs": [
        {
          "name": "ООО Ромашка",
          "city": "Москва",
          "country": "Россия",
          "startDate": 1406851200,
          "position": "Менеджер по LED освещению"
        }
      ],
      "phones": [
        "+7 900 000-00-08",
        "+7 900 000-00-48"
      ],
      "emails": ["none@rambler.ru"],
      "devices": [],
      "salary": null,
      "marriageStatus": null
    },
    {
      "network": "vkontakte",
      "id": "555555555555",
      "alias": "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
      "lastActivityTime": null,
      "cities": [],
      "jobs": [],
      "phones": ["+7 900 000-00-48"],
      "emails": ["none@rambler.ru"],
      "devices": [],
      "salary": "70 000 рублей",
      "marriageStatus": null
    }
  ],
  "universities": [
    {
      "name": "СИМТ, Саранский государственный институт информационных технологий",
      "city": "Москва",
      "country": "Россия"
    }
  ],
  "schools": [
    {
      "name": "Школа 1799",
      "city": "Москва",
      "country": "Россия"
    },
    {
      "name": "Лицей 2301",
      "city": "Москва",
      "country": "Россия"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам сначала надо обратиться к нему и получить его в какой то объект. Это можно сделать через

```
$http.get("/customUrl").then(
    function(responce){
         $scope.data = responce.data;
    }
)
```

После этого к нему можно обращаться как к объекту. Храниться он в будет в $scope.data.

UPD: После вы можете выводить как Вам потребуется, обращаясь через ng-model

Например:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.avatarURL">
```

или

```
<li><a href="item nav">{{ data.birthDate }}</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">{{ data.avatarURL }}</a></li>
<li><a href="item nav">{{ data.pages[1].network }} </a></li>
```

Comment: в ng-model  что писать?

Comment: Допустим Ваша переменная $scope.data.custom. Тогда пишите ng-model="data.custom"

Comment: var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
MyApp.controller ('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('app/infoStorage.json').sucess(function(){
        $scope.data = responce.data;
    });


}) у меня так но в браузере отображается {{ data.alias }}

Comment: sucess надо точно поправить для начала на success. А дальше надо смотреть что приходит, и как вы обращаетесь в этом случае к переменной. Что у Вас пишется в консоли браузера? Есть ли там какие ошибки?

Comment: да там была моя ошибка, с этим разобрался теперь мне нужно data.pages[1].cities без квадратных скобок вывести, сейчас выводится так ["Россия, Москва"]

Comment: пришло как массив одного элемента, как я думаю у Вас возможен и несколько элементный массив. Советую поюзать тут директиву ng-repeat. Как-то так <span ng-repeat="adress in adressBook"> {{ adress }}</span>